# No unsaved changes prompt in Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor

Tags: javascript, adobecreativesdk, creative-cloud

In my single page application, I am currently migrating from Aviary to Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor.
I noticed that the "Unsaved changes" prompt dialog does not appear anymore after completing the migration. Doing some reverse engineering, the code is still here but the show method is not being called at anytime.

Have some of you made it work, or did it just disappear with the new code?

[image]

Comment: Please share with us your integration parameters (or a link to your integration). Older versions of the Image Editor had lost the ability to suppress the modal, even if the code for suppressing it was there. When you update, if the old modal suppression code is still there, it could be that that code suddenly started working again, which might be why you don't see the modal after updating.

Comment: FYI, this bug is fixed with the latest code downloadable from adobe's SDK documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Latest version of Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor fixes it. Look for version 4.3.1.29.

Comment: I am using latest one, but still getting this issue. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Where do you find that version? The documentation only gives reference to the following URL (ie. containing /v3): http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js

Comment: Hmmm, looking inside that file, I see reference to 4.3.1.35, so I guess it is the latest version. I'm having kind of the opposite problem myself, where after saving changes and then clicking the Close button, I am re-prompted with 'Wait! You didn't save your work.'